# How to embed a Flash application into web site where application file is on a remote server

Tags: html, apache-flex, flash

I’ve developed an Adobe Flex (v. 2) application. The application exists as a .swf file hosted on a web server. I have an html page hosted on a completely different web server (which is independent of the web server the .swf file is on).

My question is how am I able to call the .swf file (that lives on the separate web server) from within the html page and have the flex application embed in the html page?
I've tried calling the url of the .swf file from within the html page.

Unfortunately I'm not getting an error message. My html page appears with nothing in it. I'm expecting to see my swf application embeded inside it.

here is an example of the code I'm using in my html page to call and embed the swf file.

```
AC_FL_RunContent(
        "src", "http://www.url/swfName.swf",
        "width", "580",
        "height", "472",
        "align", "middle",
        "id", "swfName",
        "quality", "high",
        "bgcolor", "#869ca7",
        "name", "swfName",
        "flashvars",'historyUrl=history.htm%3F&lconid=' + lc_id + '',
        "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
        "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
        "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
);
```

Am i on the right track?

Comment: What browser are you trying it in?  One of the first things I'd do is run it in Firefox with Firebug installed.  There might be some javascript errors that you're not seeing, and usually firebug will help track those down.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's some kind of a cross domain problem (meaning flash is on different domain?) so you'll need a crossdomain.xml file. Check for more about it [here](http://kb.adobe.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=tn_14213), hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it ought to work. What are you getting when you load the page?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to embed a Flash application into your web site, but the content is located on a remote server/site?  If so, you might want to change your tags and title to reach a wider audience here.